# Android's Speech Recognizer API

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am using **SpeechRecognizer** API in my Android application. I read the mechanism on how the speech recognizer API works. I have one query whether this API is **HIPPA** (Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act) compliance or not. I read the documentation related to this API but didn't found anything which states that SpeechRecognizer API is HIPPA compliance or not. Below is the API link

[Speech Recognizer API Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer)

Does anyone have any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

As an API it's just a set of names of functions and constants, and is not tied to any particular implementation. So it probably complies with most regulations.

You should find out what is the underlying implementation and what regulations it supports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering using Google Cloud Speech Recognizer. There is an informative text on this subject.

[Information-DOC](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa?hl=en)

Comment: No I want information regarding the Speech Recognizer API whether its HIPPA compliance.

Comment: I read the link which you mentioned. It only has information about Google cloud API's but no information about the API which I have asked for.